# Impute missing values using group-level summary statistics from a different dataframe

Tags: python, group-by, fillna

I want to impute missing values using the grouped summary statistics based on a different dataframe. For instance, I would like to impute missing values in `numvar_original` in `df1` to be like `numvar_ideal` where the missing values are based on group-level means from `df2`:

```
df1
catvar numvar_original numvar_ideal 
1      10              10
1      NaN             5.5
2      30              30
2      NaN             6.5


df2
catvar numvar_original
1      5
1      6
2      6
2      7

# I tried the following:
df1['numvar'].fillna(df2.groupby('catvar')['numvar'].transform('mean'), inplace=True) 
# The missing values weren't replaced 

df1['numvar'].fillna(df1.groupby('catvar')['numvar'].transform('mean'), inplace=True)  
# I checked that this works in filling up the missing values but I have to use group-level mean values from df1
```

Is there a way to do this without resorting to a combination of `apply` or `map` with a dictionary (since I've read that apply/map can be slower with larger datasets)?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and put there sample input and example output? (in text form)

Comment: I've edited to include the sample input and intended output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
means = df2.groupby("catvar")["numvar_original"].mean().to_dict()

df1 = df1.groupby("catvar", group_keys=False).apply(
    lambda x: x.fillna(means[x["catvar"].iloc[0]])
)
print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
   catvar  numvar_original  numvar_ideal
0       1             10.0          10.0
1       1              5.5           5.5
2       2             30.0          30.0
3       2              6.5           6.5
```

---

OR: Using `.merge`:

```py
means = df2.groupby("catvar")["numvar_original"].mean()

df1["numvar_original"] = df1["numvar_original"].fillna(
    df1.merge(means, on="catvar")["numvar_original_y"]
)
print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
   catvar  numvar_original  numvar_ideal
0       1             10.0          10.0
1       1              5.5           5.5
2       2             30.0          30.0
3       2              6.5           6.5
```

Comment: Thanks! Both work well with the sample dataset. However, for the first approach, how can I make it more targeted (assuming there are other variables in df1)? Currently, it seems to replace missing values in all other columns too.

Comment: @MarshaT Can you please edit your question and put there sample input/example output with new dataset?